# How to get Tree Shaking to work in Webpack 4 for React Library "material-ui"?

Tags: webpack, material-ui

Although I followed the steps explained in the docs (see [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)) to enable Tree Shaking, it seems to have no effect. I'm using `Webpack 4` with `ts-loader` for `TypeScript`. The library in question is `material-ui`. In their docs (see [How to reduce the bundle size?](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/)) they recommend to "import directly from `material-ui/` to avoid pulling in unused modules" and later they add "Both of the options should be temporary until you add tree shaking capabilities to your project.". So I assume that Tree Shaking should have some effect.

To be clear: They recommend to import like this:

```
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";
```

And not like this:

```
import {RaisedButton} from "material-ui";
```

**What I did:**

- Only used ES2015 module syntax (i.e. import and export).
- Added a `"sideEffects":false` entry to my project's `package.json` file. And made sure the spelling is correct.
- Ran Webpack in `mode: "production"`, which Webpack 4 allows to use instead of `UglifyJsPlugin` ("As of webpack 4, this is also easily toggled via the "mode" config option, set to "production".")

**Result:** Nothing. No reduction in size. So maybe I'm doing something wrong?

---

For the benchmark lovers: This is what a single `RaisedButton` costs in terms of bundle size. Without minification (i.e. production mode):

```
Initial (in mode "development"): 
1,63 MiB (No Material UI)

MuiThemeProvider
1,94 MiB -> +0,31 (`import {MuiThemeProvider} from "material-ui/styles";`)
1,92 MiB -> +0,29 (`import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';`)

RaisedButton
3,07 MiB -> +1,13 (`import {RaisedButton} from "material-ui";`)
2,03 MiB -> +0,09 (`import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";`)
```

And with minification (no compression):

```
Initial (in mode "production"):
284 KiB (No Material UI)

MuiThemeProvider
371 KiB -> +087 (`import {MuiThemeProvider} from "material-ui/styles";`)
367 KiB -> +077 (`import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';`)

RaisedButton
705 KiB -> +338 (`import {RaisedButton} from "material-ui";`)
400 KiB -> +033 (`import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";`)
```

And with Tree Shaking enabled:

```
705 KiB (`import {RaisedButton} from "material-ui";`)
400 KiB (`import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";`)
```

I.e: No effect at all.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. See https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11281 ; see also issues linked in https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11281#issuecomment-387507185

Comment: I figured my issue out (similar to yours?), with the help of those links from my previous comment. If you use webpack 4.x, use babel, add "modules": false to your babelrc env:

   "presets": [
           ["env",
            {
                "modules": false
            }],
           "react",
           "stage-0"
       ]

and if you add aliases to material-ui/es to your webpack.config.prod.js (or similar).. like so:
```
resolve: {
  ...
   alias: {
            'material-ui': 'material-ui/es'
}
```
You should be able to get tree-shaking working.

Comment: Importing differences between
import {RaisedButton} from "material-ui
import RaisedButton from "material-ui/RaisedButton";
are not important then, when using es modules and tree-shaking. That different is only important if tree-shaking is actually not working in your project, as indicated in the documentation: "Using this is fine if you have tree shaking working, however, in the case where tree shaking is not supported or configured in your build chain" - https://material-ui-next.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#how-to-reduce-the-bundle-size-

Comment: Additionally, using the webpack-bundle-analyzer was very helpful in determining, visualizing, and optimizing the bundle size: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer

Comment: You might also want to read https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/tree-shake-lodash-with-webpack-jest-and-typescript-2734fa13b5cd
In my case we don't use typescript, and use babel. The article there exposes limitations and shows a workaround, using babel (typescript for type-checking or so, still) and successfully tree-shaking lodash. Hope any of this helps. Cheers.

Comment: @rapstacke - Did you have found a solution for this problem? If so, can you please post an answer? I'm having the same problem and nothing seems to get it to work.

Comment: @Kobi Sorry, I did not find a solution and hoped that time will solve it. If you succeed to solve this, please add your answer here. I'm also still interested in this.

Comment: if there's a solution could we please post it as an answer? if there's a *partial* solution post it as a *community wiki* answer and so we can update it until it works?

Answer (score 1):

As @qx3 wrote, I've been able to get it by adding:

```
alias: { '@material-ui/core': '@material-ui/core/es' }
```

in my webpack config.

Note the '@' prefix and the '/core' suffix to adapt to the new naming of the library. This simple little thing, helped me to get rid of some bytes and enabled the team to write the '@material-ui/core' imports in a full esm compliant way.

Comment: After adding this line into web pack config I hit this error:
```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/es/TextField/TextField.js 109:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (109:46)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|     if (label) {
>       const displayRequired = InputLabelProps?.required ?? required;
```

So the solution does not work